# Edge betweenness igraph

Tags: r, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to use the edge betweenness community structure detection method from R using the igraph package. I would like the "cut" the clustering tree where I want. How can I do it? Is it even possible? I didn't understand from the guide where the default values "cut" the clustering tree. Can anyone give me some more details?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (SO)! It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to solve your problem. You can have a look at [this SO post on how to make a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My question is not a problem nor anything that doesn't work, it's a conceptual question related with hierarchical clustering of graphs.

Answer (score 4):

You can cut a dendrogram coming from a hierarchical community detection method with the `cutat()` function. The function `membership()` also cuts the tree, but it can only cut it at a single point, at the maximum modularity value:

```
g <- nexus.get("karate")
ebc <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
membership(ebc)
#    Mr Hi  Actor 2  Actor 3  Actor 4  Actor 5  Actor 6  Actor 7  Actor 8 
#        1        1        2        1        3        3        3        1 
#  Actor 9 Actor 10 Actor 11 Actor 12 Actor 13 Actor 14 Actor 15 Actor 16 
#        4        2        3        1        1        2        4        4 
# Actor 17 Actor 18 Actor 19 Actor 20 Actor 21 Actor 22 Actor 23 Actor 24 
#        3        1        4        1        4        1        4        5 
# Actor 25 Actor 26 Actor 27 Actor 28 Actor 29 Actor 30 Actor 31 Actor 32 
#        5        5        6        5        2        6        4        4 
# Actor 33   John A 
#        4        4
```

With `cutat()` you can cut it to get a certain number of communities, e.g. 3 in this case:

```
cutat(ebc, no = 3)
# [1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Or you can specify the number of merge steps to perform. Here we perform 15 merges:

```
cutat(ebc, steps = 15)
#  [1]  3  3  2  3  4  5  5  3  1  9  4 10 11  2 12 13  5 14 15 16 17 18 19  6  7
# [26]  6  8  7  2  8  1  1  1  1
```

`cutat()` does not assign names to the result, unfortunately.